# Verilog bidirectional bus for SRAM interface

Tags: verilog, bidirectional

We are attempting to write to an SRAM chip on a Terasic DE1 FPGA board, however we are getting errors to do with tri-state control. The errors are as follows:

```
Error (10137): Verilog HDL Procedural Assignment error at inputOutputControl.v(32): object "SRAM_DATA" on left-hand side of assignment must have a variable data type
Error (10137): Verilog HDL Procedural Assignment error at inputOutputControl.v(33): object "SRAM_DATA" on left-hand side of assignment must have a variable data type
Error (10219): Verilog HDL Continuous Assignment error at inputOutputControl.v(52): object "SRAM_LB_N" on left-hand side of assignment must have a net type
Error (10219): Verilog HDL Continuous Assignment error at inputOutputControl.v(53): object "SRAM_UB_N" on left-hand side of assignment must have a net type
```

The module we are having trouble with is shown below, can anybody shed any light on how we can get this working?

```
module ram_writer(
input               CLK,
input               RESET_N,
input               V_PORCH_EN,
input               LOGIC_WE_N,
input               LOGIC_CE_N,
input        [17:0] LOGIC_WRITE_ADDRESS,        
input        [15:0] LOGIC_WRITE_DATA,
input               VGA_OE_N,
input               VGA_CE_N,
input        [17:0] VGA_READ_ADDRESS,       
output       [15:0] VGA_READ_DATA,
output  reg         SRAM_OE_N,
output  reg         SRAM_WE_N,
output  reg         SRAM_CE_N,
output  reg         SRAM_LB_N,
output  reg         SRAM_UB_N,
output  reg  [17:0] SRAM_ADDRESS,       
inout   wire [15:0] SRAM_DATA   
);

reg [15:0] writeData;

always @(posedge CLK)
begin
   writeData       <= LOGIC_WRITE_DATA;                    
   VGA_READ_DATA   <= SRAM_DATA;
end

always @((posedge LOGIC_WE_N or writeData))
begin
   if( LOGIC_WE_N == 1) SRAM_DATA = 16'bZ;
   else SRAM_DATA = writeData; 
end

always @(posedge CLK)
begin
   if(V_PORCH_EN == 1) begin
   SRAM_ADDRESS <= LOGIC_WRITE_ADDRESS;
   SRAM_CE_N    <= LOGIC_CE_N;
   SRAM_WE_N    <= LOGIC_WE_N; 
   SRAM_OE_N    <= 1;
   end 
   else begin
   SRAM_ADDRESS <= VGA_READ_ADDRESS;
   SRAM_CE_N    <= VGA_CE_N;
   SRAM_OE_N    <= VGA_OE_N; 
   SRAM_WE_N    <= 1;
   end 
end

assign SRAM_LB_N = 0; 
assign SRAM_UB_N = 0; 

endmodule
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this:

```
Error (10137): Verilog HDL Procedural Assignment error at inputOutputControl.v(32): object "SRAM_DATA" on left-hand side of assignment must have a variable data type
Error (10137): Verilog HDL Procedural Assignment error at inputOutputControl.v(33): object "SRAM_DATA" on left-hand side of assignment must have a variable data type
```

Refers to this:

```
if( LOGIC_WE_N == 1) SRAM_DATA = 16'bZ;
else SRAM_DATA = writeData;
```

A 'wire' datatype has no memory, so you have to assign it using continuous assignment, not an always block.

Conversely here:

```
assign SRAM_LB_N = 0; 
assign SRAM_UB_N = 0;
```

You cannot assign a reg type via continuous assignment, it must be assigned in an always block.

Comment: Thanks for the help, we've changed the SRAM_LB_N and SRAM_UB_N to wire types, however we're still not sure about how to fix the SRAM_DATA error? Can an inout port be a reg?

Comment: Try creating a reg type SRAM_DATA_REG which you assign via an always block, and then 'assign SRAM_DATA = SRAM_DATA_REG;'

Comment: Or Keep it as a wire typeand just do:

      assign SRAM_DATA = LOGIC_WE_N ? 16'bZ : writeData ;